# how to add an item to combobox so that my last added item should be shown at the top

Tags: vb.net, combobox

In VB.net:
using combobox1.items.add(name) will append the combobox items. But i want to see the combobox list, last added item at the first. As of now, i'm moving the items to an array and then i move the values from last to first using a for loop. Is there a short way to do this?

Code:

```
        For i As Integer = (RC_Array.Length - 1) To 0 Step -1
            RC_Combobox.Items.Add(RC_Array(i)) 'Move the last value first
        Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ComboBox.Items.Insert(0,Item)` to insert an item at the first slot of the combo box.